# How can I pick a random variable, and then pick a random variable from the variable's list?

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

I have two buttons. One for a random movie flavor, ex. ['love', 'war', 'true']. I have this working. The problem, the second button is supposed to pick a random movie from the movie flavor that was picked. Ex. If "Love" is picked, the a new random would come from the Love List ['Noel', 'Titanic', 'Pearl Harbor']. Appreciate any help, thank you all ... ^ _ ^ ...

```
var movieFlavor = ['Love', 'War', 'True'];



var loveMovies = ['Titanic', 'Noel', 'Pearl Harbor',

]


var warMovies = ['PT-109', 'Firebase Gloria', 'Pearl Harbor',

]

var trueMovies = ['PT-109', 'Remember the Titians', 'Pearl Harbor',
]


function newRandomMovieFlavor() {
    var randomFlavor = Math.floor(Math.random() * (movieFlavor.length));
    document.getElementById('movieDisplay1').innerHTML = movieFlavor[randomFlavor];
}


function newRandomMovie() {
    var randomMovie = Math.floor(Math.random() * (movieFlavor.length * randomFlavor));
    document.getElementById('movieDisplay2').innerHTML = movieFlavor.length * randomFlavor[randomMovie];
}
```

Comment: You will need to provide your current code in your question in order for us to help you properly

Answer (score 1):

With `Math.floor(Math.random() * moviesByType.length)` you can generate the random index within the range of array length.

I maintained a dictionary of movies with movie-type as a key.

When the button is clicked, we can read the `movie-type` attribute and then get the list from the dictionary by type and return a random element from that array.

```js
const movieList = {
  love: ['Love1', 'Love2', 'Love3'],
  war: ['War1', 'War2', 'War3'],
  true: ['True1', 'True2', 'True3']
};

const getRandomMovie = (e) => {
  const type = e.target.getAttribute('movie-type');
  let moviesByType = movieList[type] || [];
  
  if(moviesByType.length) {
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * moviesByType.length);
    const movie = moviesByType[randomIndex];
    console.log(`${type}: ${movie}`);
  }
}

document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(btn => btn.onclick=getRandomMovie);
```

```html
<button movie-type="love">
  Love
</button>
<button movie-type="war">
  War
</button>
<button movie-type="true">
  True
</button>
```